# Remove Related To from Email Layout

Tags: lightning

This is from Salesforce Contact (Email sending layout)

[image]

After clicking on "Write an email...", we can compose an email directly from Salesforce as shown below.

[image]

I am aware that this is an out of the box standard functionality, but I was wondering whether it is possible to remove this "Related To" from the layout itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the option finally in the Global Actions as shown below

[image]

Here you can remove "Related To" from the layout